# TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"

Tags: compiler-errors

//function withdraw() public payable {
msg.sender.transfer(address(this));

}

This brings up error. can someone please help?

using pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;//

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? The transfer function works when you are trying to send funds from the smart contract not in. To send the funds in

You need to create either receive() function or something like this:

```
function deposit() public payable {}
```

And when you call that function send some eth with it.

If you want to send eth from the smart contract it should look like this

```
function withdraw(address payable _addressToSendTo, uint256 _amount) public {
    _addresToSendTo.transfer(_amount);
}
// if you want to send the funds to msg.sender you have to wrap it like this 

payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amount);
```